# Creating subplot for multiple columns using loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DataFrame whose list of columns look like this.

```
 df.columns
 ['dr1', 'r1', 'dr9', 'r9', 'dr21', 'r21', 'dr26', 'r26',
       'dr32', 'r32', 'dr37', 'r37', 'dr49', 'r49', 'dr52', 'r52',
       'dr105', 'r105', 'dr118', 'r118']
DF= 
               dr1          r1            dr9           r9           dr21           r21        dr26              r26        dr32           r32          dr37             r37           dr49               r49      dr52       r52           dr105           r105          dr118            r118   
            1.370077e-03    79.492551   1.885239e-03    91.721574   1.799699e-03    75.545364   7.945449e-04    56.431429   1.608503e-02    81.127766   2.142295e-03    68.240745   1.079295e-03    81.316295   6.329889e-03    75.426940   3.396244e-03    73.181260   3.068635e-03    74.735711
        1   6.434528e-04    75.018284   1.793570e-03    89.052090   2.371287e-03    72.617954   8.695473e-04    52.827016   1.322238e-02    77.128761   2.404007e-03    66.440905   1.290229e-03    77.116401   3.996065e-03    71.487773   3.867551e-03    69.449838   2.715589e-03    70.733729
        2   4.515897e-04    71.005130   2.193572e-03    86.580311   2.479454e-03    69.926743   8.851577e-04    49.512332   1.333745e-02    73.533564   2.027752e-03    64.363379   1.173162e-03    72.735975   2.546558e-03    67.581776   3.918930e-03    65.663389   2.571297e-03    66.733496
        3   4.306166e-04    67.021659   2.013258e-03    83.587133   2.331958e-03    67.171358   9.085228e-04    46.485528   1.455461e-02    69.784763   1.783866e-03    62.075661   1.109990e-03    68.369232   2.612790e-03    63.726161   3.752804e-03    61.925863   2.718291e-03    63.163573
        4   4.106338e-04    63.078692   2.162847e-03    80.224832   2.552906e-03    64.217342   9.786517e-04    43.847398   1.431416e-02    65.971753   1.601472e-03    59.616326   1.174008e-03    64.488470   2.752785e-03    60.275407   4.022395e-03    58.637315   2.613834e-03    59.649589
```

I want to create a subplot with multiple graphs between each **`r vs dr`.**
I am able to do this by individually calling each subplot axis, but I want to automate this using loop. What can be done to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.wide_to_long` to turn your data into long form, then plot with pandas' groupby:

```
long_data = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['r','dr'], i='index', j='type').reset_index()
long_data.groupby('type').plot(x='r',y='dr')
```

Or with seaborn's FacetGrid:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=long_data, col='type', col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'r','dr')
```

Output (with seaborn):

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to use a secondary Y-Axis on all these subplots here; And plot another variable on that Y-axis? I tried with twinx() but that doesn't work.